# Custom .Net library or existing library to handle sequence formatting?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I am thinking a library already exists for this, but I need allow my users to create a numbering format for their documents.

For example, let's say we have an RFI from and the user has a specific format the numbering sequence needs to be in. A typical RFI number looks like this for their system:  R0000100. The next RFI in line would be R0000101.

Before I set out to creating a formatting engine for numbers such as these, does something already exist that can accommodate this?

Update:
I failed to save the edit to this question. Anyway, I also want to give the users the ability to create their own formats. So, I may have a form where they can input the format: R#######  And also allow them to specify the starting integer:  in the case 100. Also, I may want to allow them to specify how they want to increment. maybe only by 100s. So the next number may be R0000200. I know this may sound ridiculous, but you never know. That is why I asked if something like this already exists.

Comment: You are looking for a _library_ to increment values? Really?

Comment: Where are these sequences stored?

Comment: you want to format a number? like `string.Format("R{0:0000000}", 100);`

Comment: @Oded, not what I was asking. I was asking about formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep value and format separated, you won't need a library or such a thing.

The numbers would be simple, say, integers `i`, i.e. 100, 101, 102, that you manage/store however you see fit. The formatting part would simply be a matter of `R + i.ToString("0000000")`, or if you want to have the format as a string literal `string.Format("R{0:0000000}", i)`.

I know, this might only be an example, but as your question stands, the formatting options, that .NET provides out of the box seem to suffice.

Comment: @yas4891 Thanks, and sorry for making it look like hijacking, but I didn't see your comment until I posted my answer (maybe SO should provide a "a new comment has been added [reload]" option like it does for answers ;-)

Comment: ha ha. No worries, mate. Your answer is pretty decent

Answer (score 1):

The incrementing of identity field values is most often handled in an RDBMS-style database.  This comes with a few benefits, such as built-in concurrency handling.  If you want to generate the values yourself, a simple class to get the last-issued value and increment by one would be very easy to create.  Make it thread-safe so you don't get any duplicates or gaps and you'll be good to go.